# How can I toggle a class using a boolean in a Polymer template?

Tags: css, polymer, responsive, templating

Would like to achieve this **without** using a helper function as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754824/how-can-do-an-expression-in-polymer). I know I can use some basic operators (i.e. `!`), but would like to use a bit more logic in templating. Basically the aim is to use the Boolean value set via `iron-media-query` to toggle a class on an element.

Pseudo code:

```
<div class$="[[(mobile)?'mobile-styling':null]]"></div>
```

P.S. the class name cannot be the boolean variable name.

Thanks

Comment: Most expressions aren't allowed in Polymer's binding syntax. Just properties, functions and the negation operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally add css class in polymer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228515/conditionally-add-css-class-in-polymer)

Comment: **Without** helper function Ben. I had already linked to an answer that uses this technique. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature has been deprecated for performance improvements. polymer 1.0+ only support the following:

1. A property or subproperty path (users, address.street).
2. A computed binding (_computeName(firstName, lastName, locale)).
3. Any of the above, preceded by the negation operator (!).

here is an example for how you can achieve computed binding:

```
<dom-module ...>
  <template>
    <div class$="[[hasMobileStyle(mobile)]]"></div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ...
      hasMobileStyle: function(mobile) {
        return mobile ? 'mobile-styling' : '';
      }
    });
  <script>
</dom-module>
```

you can also use the boolean as a selector to get rid of the computed binding:

```
<div class$="mobile-styling--[[mobile]]"></div>
```

and you'd do a selector on `.mobile-styling--true`

What you are asking for cannot be done. only the three conditions work, `[[(mobile)?'mobile-styling':null]]` does not fit the criteria.

Comment: No, I didn't change the question. I simply put without in bold... See the edit...

Comment: regardless, my post still answers your question :)

Comment: Well, you answered but it certainly didn't answer my question :) . **Without** using a helper function, but thanks, I am using something similar to that at the moment.. there is a cleaner way though

Comment: clearly there is no way to achieve it without a helper function, its clearly stated in the docs.

Comment: Then I guess the answer to the question is no Ahmad. I'll mark this as correct for now, hopefully this will functionality will be available in future!